# iOS Push notifications have stopped working in Sandbox org

Tags: mobilesdk

We have already raised this issue to the SDK Team but they passed us to SF Support and when we raised this to SF Support, they suggested to just post a question here as this is the fastest way to resolve Mobile SDK issue.

ISSUE

We can't receive push notification for all the cases logged by all the users. It was working before but the functionality has stopped on our Sandbox org during the preview dates for Summer '19.

EXPECTED RESULT/UX

I should receive a Push Notification within seconds, for the auto-response to the case I just opened

ACTUAL RESULT/UX (bug)

I do NOT receive a Push Notification at all, for the auto-response to the case I just opened

Reproduction steps

1. I open the iOS app (any version)
2. I authenticate as a new user or an existing user
3. Press "Get in touch” button from More screen
4. I open a new case and fill in all mandatory fields
5. Click Submit

RESULT: *** No push notification received****

VERSION OF SDK COMPONENTS BEING USED

All SDK version

DEVICE(s) AND VERSION(s) of IOS BEING USED

iOS 11.0 and above

Is this related to Summer '19 release?

The last time we raised this with the SF Support, it was related to our Android app but was resolved by the patch release of Summer '19. Now, the issue is on the IOS side.

Comment: I've made some edits to this question to reflect the fact that Salesforce Stack Exchange is not an official support channel, but a community knowledge base. We can't field urgent support issues, but there's a lot of interest around changes in Summer '19 that may affect other community members.

Comment: As per checking in Prod, ios push notification is working fine. It is only not working in Sandbox. Can you help us know what is the issue here?